# Call a function after change in input box which is made by select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select box which after change fire a script (and made a change of date in input text field):

```
$(window).load(function() {
  datum = function() {
    var platba = document.getElementById('payment').value;
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
    if (payment = 'yes') { datet = today; }
    document.getElementById('datepayment').value = datet;
```

It works great, but now I need to call a jQuery function which save the new value into dtb...

This is made by following script (which works automatically after change in input fields in whole form):

```
<!--JQUERY-->
<script type='text/javascript'>
// JQUERY: Plugin 'autoSumbit'
(function($) {
    $.fn.autoSubmit = function(options) {
        return $.each(this, function() {
            // VARIABLES: Input-specific
            var input = $(this);
            var column = input.attr('name');

            // VARIABLES: Form-specific
            var form = input.parents('form');
            var method = form.attr('method');
            var action = form.attr('action');

            // VARIABLES: Where to update in database
            var where_val = form.find('#where').val();
            var where_col = form.find('#where').attr('name');

    // ONBLUR: Dynamic value send through Ajax
            input.bind('blur', function(event) {

                // Get latest value
                var value = input.val();

                // AJAX: Send values
                $.ajax({
                    url: action,
                    type: method,
                    data: {
                        val: value,
                        col: column,
                        w_col: where_col,
                        w_val: where_val
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 10000,
                    success: function(data) {
                        // Alert if update failed
                        if (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                        // Load output into a P
                        else {
                            $('#notice').text('Updated');
                            $('#notice').fadeOut().fadeIn();
                        }
                    }

                });
                // Prevent normal submission of form

      return false; 
            })
         //  
        });

    }
})(jQuery);
// JQUERY: Run .autoSubmit() on all INPUT fields within form
$(function(){
  $('#ajax-form INPUT').autoSubmit();
  $('#ajax-form SELECT').autoSubmit(); 
  $('#ajax-form TEXTAREA').autoSubmit();         
});
</script>
```

Question is: how to save the value in field datepayment into database without click into it? Thank you for comments!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
input.bind('blur', function(event)
```

Try

```
input.on('input', function() {
```

Here is a simple example:

```
<input type="text" id="input1"/> 
<input type="text" id="input2"/> 
<select id="input3">
<option value="ABC">ABC</option>
<option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input1").on('input', function() { //'input' listener
    alert($("#input1").val());
  });
  $("#input2").on('input', function() { //'input' listener
    alert($("#input2").val());
  });
  $("#input3").on('change', function() { //'change' listener
    alert($("#input3").val());
  });
});
```

jsfiddle link: **https://jsfiddle.net/kannanore/xdat6axa/**

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but it did'nt helped. I guess that the change (the new value) in the text field is not "the change" :)

Comment: Still not working. Maybe the problem is that the script has to be fired twice - first time to save SELECT #payment and second time to save text field #datepayment...

Comment: It should be fired for each and every field. You may try adding 'input' listener to all the necessary fields in your form

Comment: I'm sorry, but now I don't understand what do you mean (by the input listener)... Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Now look at the code in answer, each fields (i.e. input1,input2, and input3) are having a listener. input1 and input2 are having an 'input' listener and input3 is having a 'change' listener.